# Get the mean of comma-separated values using AWK

Tags: awk, mean

I have the following data, separated by spaces:

```
SampleX=1,1,2,3 SampleY=1,1,2,3 SampleZ=1,1,2,3 
SampleX=0,0,0,1 SampleY=.,.,.,. SampleZ=0,1,1,1
```

I want to do a summary of each row, getting the mean for each value in all samples, ignoring dots. So first row, there are 3 samples, each sample contains 4 values. The mean of each value are represented as follows:

```
A B C D
1 1 2 3
0 0.5 0.5 1
```

I already did something similar but instead of mean, I got counts as follows:

```
SampleX=1/1 SampleY=0/0 SampleZ=1/1 
SampleX=0/1 SampleY=./. SampleZ=1/0
```

Result is count of events (0/0=A, 1/0 or 0/1=B and 1/1=C)

```
A B C
1 0 2
0 2 0
```

Using:

```
    echo "SampleA=1/1 SampleB=0/0 SampleC=1/1 
SampleA=0/1 SampleB=./. SampleC=1/0" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "A\tB\tC"} {B=gsub(/0\|1|1\|0|0\/1|1\/0/, ""); A=sub(/1\|1|1\/1/, ""); C=gsub(/0\|0|0\/0/, ""); print A,B,C}'
```

But I'm not sure how to do the same with commas and get the mean instead of counts.

Comment: How you can render `A B C D` where there's 3 columns???

Comment: But there is 4 columns after each = , even tough there are only 3 samples. I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Is it mandatory to use 'awk' ? Perl is not welcome ?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is an example dataset but the real dataset contain millions of lines which I know I can process with AWK relatively fast. Also, I'm manipulating the file with AWK with pipes, not sure if pearl would combine well

Comment: Perl not Pearl....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    delete tot
    delete cnt
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        n = split($i,f,/[=,]/)
        for ( j=2; j<=n; j++ ) {
            if ( f[j] != "." ) {
                tot[j] += f[j]
                cnt[j] ++
            }
        }
    }
    if ( NR == 1 ) {
        for ( j=2; j<=n; j++ ) {
            val = substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",j-1,1)
            printf "%s%s", val, (j<n ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for ( j=2; j<=n; j++ ) {
        val = ( cnt[j] ? tot[j] / cnt[j] : 0 )
        printf "%s%s", val, (j<n ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
A B C D
1 1 2 3
0 0.5 0.5 1
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would do using Perl (it should not be too slow):

```
perl -F'=([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+)' -ne '
    BEGIN{ our $max = 3; }

    foreach my $i (0..2) {
        my $mymax = $max;
        --$mymax if grep { /\./ } @F[1+$i,6+$i,11+$i];
        my $sum = 0;
        map { $sum += $_ } @F[1+$i,6+$i,11+$i];
        printf "%.1f", $sum/$mymax;
        print $i == 2 ? "\n" : " ";
    }
' file
```

```
1.0 1.0 2.0 
0.0 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: Something weird is happening, because it is counting . as 0, thus influencing on the mean values!

Comment: How the script should handle '.'  ? What do you expect ? Is it a typo from your sample input? A placeholder?

Comment: It just denotes missing values! They are there, but are non-numerical if that makes sense

Comment: Post edited accordingly to skip values with dots.

Comment: New version, more reliable

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion using awk.
File `script.awk` :

```
{
gsub(/[^ ]+=/, "")
gsub(/\./, "0")
nSamples = NF
nValues = split($0, Values, /[ ,]/) / nSamples
for(Index = 1; Index <= nValues; ++ Index)
  {
  Offset = nValues
  for(Count = 1; Count < nSamples; ++ Count)
    {
    Values[Index] += Values[Index + Offset]
    Offset += nValues
    }
  $Index = sprintf("%.1f", Values[Index] / nSamples)
  }
 print $0
}
```

With an input file (`input.txt`) containing the following :

```
SampleX=1,1,2,3 SampleY=1,1,2,3 SampleZ=1,1,2,3
SampleX=5,4,3,2 SampleY=1,5,9,2 SampleZ=7,6,5,4
SampleX=9,1,3,5 SampleY=2,6,1,3 SampleZ=1,1,2,3
SampleX=9,1,3,5 SampleY=.,6,.,3 SampleZ=1,1,2,3
```

... if you execute `awk -f script.awk input.txt`, you should obtain :

```
1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
4.3 5.0 5.7 2.7
4.0 2.7 2.0 3.7
3.3 2.7 1.7 3.7
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Count <= nSamples` --> `Count < nSamples` (corrected)